# Mysql return array with right data types

Tags: php, mysql, types, sqldatatypes

I have a database table `client` which contains a field `id INT(6)` (with a primary key and auto increment). I select the last `id` using:

```
$findClient = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `client` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
$client = mysql_fetch_assoc($findClient))
var_dump($client);
```

What happens to be is that the id in the array has become in string while it is an integer in the database. Why can this be resolved neatly? I need it to be an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that it is `int`, you can always cast it manually. Otherwise, look at `mysql_field_type()` to get the type of the field.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal. All rows that are fetched from a result are arrays of strings.
If You want the id value as int, simply change the data type:

```
$result['id'] = (int) $result['id'];
```

Comment: @j0k Well, the documentation on mysql_fetch_assoc says "Returns an associative array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows."

Comment: Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php#refsect1-function.mysql-fetch-assoc-returnvalues